# Drawing simple edge, no arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={draw,font=\bfseries}]
  \node[main node] (111) at (0,1) {$X_{1,1}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (121) at (0,2) {$X_{1,2}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (1n1) at (0,4) {$X_{1,n}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (211) at (0,6) {$X_{2,1}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (221) at (0,7) {$X_{2,2}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (2n1) at (0,9) {$X_{2,n}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (n11) at (0,11) {$X_{n,1}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (n21) at (0,12) {$X_{n,2}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (nn1) at (0,14) {$X_{n,n}^{(1)}$};
  \node[main node] (112) at (2.5,1) {$X_{1,1}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (122) at (2.5,2) {$X_{1,2}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (1n2) at (2.5,4) {$X_{1,n}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (212) at (2.5,6) {$X_{2,1}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (222) at (2.5,7) {$X_{2,2}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (2n2) at (2.5,9) {$X_{2,n}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (n12) at (2.5,11) {$X_{n,1}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (n22) at (2.5,12) {$X_{n,2}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (nn2) at (2.5,14) {$X_{n,n}^{(2)}$};
  \node[main node] (11k) at (6,1) {$X_{1,1}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (12k) at (6,2) {$X_{1,2}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (1nk) at (6,4) {$X_{1,n}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (21k) at (6,6) {$X_{2,1}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (22k) at (6,7) {$X_{2,2}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (2nk) at (6,9) {$X_{2,n}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (n1k) at (6,11) {$X_{n,1}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (n2k) at (6,12) {$X_{n,2}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (nnk) at (6,14) {$X_{n,n}^{(k)}$};
  \node[main node] (11n2) at (9.5,1) {$X_{1,1}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (12n2) at (9.5,2) {$X_{1,2}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (1nn2) at (9.5,4) {$X_{1,n}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (21n2) at (9.5,6) {$X_{2,1}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (22n2) at (9.5,7) {$X_{2,2}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (2nn2) at (9.5,9) {$X_{2,n}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (n1n2) at (9.5,11) {$X_{n,1}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (n2n2) at (9.5,12) {$X_{n,2}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (nnn2) at (9.5,14) {$X_{n,n}^{(n-2)}$};
  \node[main node] (11n1) at (12,1) {$X_{1,1}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (12n1) at (12,2) {$X_{1,2}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (1nn1) at (12,4) {$X_{1,n}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (21n1) at (12,6) {$X_{2,1}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (22n1) at (12,7) {$X_{2,2}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (2nn1) at (12,9) {$X_{2,n}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (n1n1) at (12,11) {$X_{n,1}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (n2n1) at (12,12) {$X_{n,2}^{(n-1)}$};
  \node[main node] (nnn1) at (12,14) {$X_{n,n}^{(n-1)}$};
  \path
    (111) edge (112)
        edge (122)
        edge (1n2)
    (121) edge (112)
        edge (122)
        edge (1n2)
    (1n1) edge (112)
        edge (122)
        edge (1n2)
    (121) edge[--,dashed] (1n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I just want simple lines, no arrows.
How to manage with `edge` to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Use a single `-` instead of a double one for switching off the arrow locally.

Comment: What about removing `->` from the options to the `tikzpicture` environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's also beneficial to use `matrix` nodes to reduce the typing labor. I used to a small Excel file to strip down the node names and to populate the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw,font=\bfseries},row sep ={1cm,between origins},column sep={2cm,between origins}] (m) {
X_{n,n}^{(1)} &[0.5cm] X_{n,n}^{(2)} &[2cm] X_{n,n}^{(k)} &[1cm] X_{n,n}^{(n-2)} &[0.5cm] X_{n,n}^{(n-1)}\\[1cm]
X_{n,2}^{(1)} &        X_{n,2}^{(2)} &      X_{n,2}^{(k)} &      X_{n,2}^{(n-2)} &        X_{n,2}^{(n-1)}\\
X_{n,1}^{(1)} &        X_{n,1}^{(2)} &      X_{n,1}^{(k)} &      X_{n,1}^{(n-2)} &        X_{n,1}^{(n-1)}\\[1cm]
X_{2,n}^{(1)} &        X_{2,n}^{(2)} &      X_{2,n}^{(k)} &      X_{2,n}^{(n-2)} &        X_{2,n}^{(n-1)}\\[1cm]
X_{2,2}^{(1)} &        X_{2,2}^{(2)} &      X_{2,2}^{(k)} &      X_{2,2}^{(n-2)} &        X_{2,2}^{(n-1)}\\
X_{2,1}^{(1)} &        X_{2,1}^{(2)} &      X_{2,1}^{(k)} &      X_{2,1}^{(n-2)} &        X_{2,1}^{(n-1)}\\[1cm]
X_{1,n}^{(1)} &        X_{1,n}^{(2)} &      X_{1,n}^{(k)} &      X_{1,n}^{(n-2)} &        X_{1,n}^{(n-1)}\\[1cm]
X_{1,2}^{(1)} &        X_{1,2}^{(2)} &      X_{1,2}^{(k)} &      X_{1,2}^{(n-2)} &        X_{1,2}^{(n-1)}\\
X_{1,1}^{(1)} &        X_{1,1}^{(2)} &      X_{1,1}^{(k)} &      X_{1,1}^{(n-2)} &        X_{1,1}^{(n-1)}\\
};
  \path[thick]
    (m-7-1) edge (m-7-2)
        edge (m-8-2)
        edge (m-9-2)
    (m-8-1) edge (m-7-2)
        edge (m-8-2)
        edge (m-9-2)
    (m-9-1) edge (m-7-2)
        edge (m-8-2)
        edge (m-9-2)
    (m-7-1) edge[-,dashed] (m-8-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

There is no arrow with `edge` by default, but you have turned on arrows for all lines in the `tikzpicture` with the `->` argument:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto,node distance=3cm,
   thick,main node/.style={draw,font=\bfseries}]
```

Remove `->` and there are no arrows.

Or as commented by Jake, use `-` as an argument to the `\path` (or `edge`) to remove the arrows locally.

```
\path[-]
(111) edge (112)
    edge (122)
    edge (1n2)
(121) edge (112)
    edge (122)
    edge (1n2)
(1n1) edge (112)
    edge (122)
    edge (1n2)
(121) edge[dashed] (1n1);
```

You could also put the `\path` drawing the lines in a `scope` environment and use the same argument. Could be convenient if you had several `\path`/`\draw` commands for which you wanted to apply this.

```
\begin{scope}[-]
  \path
  (111) edge (112)
      edge (122)
      edge (1n2)
    (121) edge (112)
      edge (122)
      edge (1n2)
  (1n1) edge (112)
      edge (122)
       edge (1n2)
  (121) edge[dashed] (1n1);
\end{scope}
```