# Draw lines without arrows between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, edge

The answer referenced is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45735/180050 and is essential for this question.

In the given answer, it shows how you can easily make directed edges between specified nodes.

I was wondering how I could do the same but with undirected edges (lines with no arrows).

**Edit:**

I appreciate the linked duplicate, and I used Jake's comment to the main post of adding [-] to edge for typical edges. However, this does not work for self-loops, and fixing that is not in the linked solution.

Comment: Remove `->` and `shorten>=1pt` from the option list of the `tikzpicture` environment.  For the  loops you have to add `every loop/.style={}`.

Comment: @esdd I used Jake's comment to the main post here to solve the typical edge: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/drawing-simple-edge-no-arrow

Comment: Is it possible to use something like edge[-] for a self-loop instead of changing the global settings? Like just remove the arrow from one loop with the default being to have the arrows?

Comment: I saw your post in the reopening queue and am wondering if you are simply looking for `every loop/.append style={-}` in the options of the `tikzpicture`. Notice that I did not (vote to) close your question, but I can see why people could want to close it. It would be much better if you added a simple example such that it is clear what you want (unless the above solved it already). Once this is done I will be happy to help you reopening the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global switching off of arrows can be achieved as in [esdd's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487315/draw-lines-without-arrows-between-nodes/487480?noredirect=1#comment1230734_487315) or bay saying `very loop/.append style={-}`. Local switching off works essentially the same, I added a style `no arrow` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
                    thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
                    no arrow/.style={-,every loop/.append style={-}}
                    ]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {3};
  \node[main node] (4) [below right of=1] {4};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [left] {0.6} (4)
        edge [bend right] node[left] {0.3} (2)
        edge [no arrow,loop above] node {0.1} (1)
    (2) edge node [right] {0.4} (1)
        edge node {0.3} (4)
        edge [loop left] node {0.4} (2)
        edge [bend right] node[left] {0.1} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {0.8} (2)
        edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (4)
    (4) edge node [left] {0.2} (3)
        edge [loop right] node {0.6} (4)
        edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing me how I can universally do it! Is there a way to have it such that the default adds an arrow and you can locally choose to make it not have an arrow?

Comment: Like how you can change `edge node [left] {0.6} (4)` to `edge [-] node [left] {0.6} (4)` to make a nonloop edge not have an arrow?

Comment: @GigiBayte2 Yes, it works the same way. I added a style `no arrow` that makes this more convenient. (One may argue that just adding `->` is not such a great idea, but I take you want to keep this.)

Comment: Hi! Would it be possible to add an allowable style for each node similar to how you did the "no arrow" style to fill the node a certain color?

Comment: @GigiBayte2 `\tikzset{every node/.append style={fill=blue}}`?

Comment: Ah... I just realized that I can do fill=blue in the creation of the nodes like \node[fill=blue, main node]...